# Infopaht form: once repeating table is created, how can i add display rows to be default?

Tags: infopath, display-template

I created the repeating table with two rows display initially, but i would like to have 5 rows instead.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As it is a repeating table, only a single row will appear by default. You will need to add the number rows as per your requirement at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Find the Default Values button and add more instances. I think it's on the Data tab.